# applying same css to an element more than once

Tags: css

I want give same `CSS` property to one element more than one. for example when mouse is on element it's scale change to 1.5 and after .2s it's scale changed to 1.2.
i try:

```
-moz-transform:scale(1.5);
-moz-transition:1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transform:scale(1.2);
```

but it not working and only it scale changed to 1.2. is it possible?

Comment: It's cascading style sheets, meaning the last found property of an element applies. For what you're trying to do use JavaScript

Comment: Have a look at [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes).

Comment: You could use css keyframes ( @keyframes )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using keyframes.
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dUsep/

```
@-moz-keyframes myanimation {
from { -moz-transform:scale(1.5);}
to {-moz-transform:scale(1.2);}
}


.mybox:hover{
    -moz-animation: myanimation 1s;
}
```